# Reordering facet_wrap by percentage value in the titles

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

**Question**

I would like to reorder my facet_wrap by the values in the title. Currently, the lowest value is in the upper left corner with the highest value (percentage) in the lower right corner. Is there any way to reorder the facets so the highest value is in the top left and the lowest in the bottom right?

**Current Code**

```r
#Vector of state abbreviations in descending order of percentage difference (calcluated separately)
top_colleges_pct_change <- c('KS', 'NV', 'NY', 'TX', 'OH', 'LA', 'AZ', 'MS', 'OK', "NC", "PA", "CA")

tuition_cost_clean %>% 
  filter(!is.na(room_and_board),
         degree_length == "4 Year",
         state_abbr %in% top_colleges_pct_change) %>% 
  arrange(state, desc(in_state_total)) %>%
  group_by(state_abbr) %>% 
  slice(which.max(in_state_total), which.min(in_state_total)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = round(-diff(in_state_total) / max(in_state_total),3),) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  top_n(n = 24, wt = pct_change) %>% 
  select(name, state_abbr, in_state_total, pct_change) %>% 
  mutate(label=paste(pct_change * 100,"%")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = state_abbr, y = in_state_total, fill = name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~label, scales = "free")+
  labs(title = "States with Largest Difference Between Highest and Lowest Costing 4-Year Colleges\n2018-2019",
       x = "State",
       y = "In-State Total Cost")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)
```

**Current Output**
[image: ggplot2 image with mis-ordered facets]

**Reproducible Data**

```r
tuition_cost_clean <- structure(list(name = c("Aaniiih Nakoda College", "Abilene Christian University", 
"Abraham Baldwin Agricultural College", "Academy College", "Academy of Art University", 
"Adams State University", "Adelphi University", "Adirondack Community College", 
"Adrian College", "Advanced Technology Institute", "Adventist University of Health Sciences", 
"Agnes Scott College", "Aiken Technical College", "Aims Community College", 
"Alabama Agricultural and Mechanical University", "Alabama Southern Community College", 
"Alabama State University", "Alamance Community College", "Alaska Bible College", 
"Alaska Pacific University", "Albany College of Pharmacy and Health Sciences", 
"Albany State University", "Albany Technical College", "Albertus Magnus College", 
"Albion College", "Albright College", "Alcorn State University", 
"Alderson-Broaddus University", "Alexandria Technical and Community College", 
"Alfred University", "Allan Hancock College", "Allegany College of Maryland", 
"Allegheny College", "Allegheny Wesleyan College", "Allen College", 
"Allen County Community College", "Allen University", "Alliant International University", 
"Alma College", "Alpena Community College", "Alvernia University", 
"Alverno College", "Alvin Community College", "Amarillo College", 
"Amberton University", "American Academy McAllister Institute of Funeral Service", 
"American Academy of Art", "American Academy of Dramatic Arts", 
"American Academy of Dramatic Arts: West", "American Baptist College", 
"American Indian College of the Assemblies of God", "American International College", 
"American Jewish University", "American National University: Charlottesville", 
"American National University: Danville", "American National University: Harrisonburg", 
"American National University: Lynchburg", "American National University: Martinsville", 
"American National University: Salem", "American  University SystemFor-profit", 
"American River College", "American Samoa Community College", 
"American University", "American University of Puerto Rico", 
"Amherst College", "Amridge University", "Ancilla College", "Anderson University", 
"Anderson University", "Andrew College", "Andrews University", 
"Angelina College", "Angelo State University", "Anna Maria College", 
"Anne Arundel Community College", "Anoka Technical College", 
"Anoka-Ramsey Community College", "Antelope Valley College", 
"Antioch College", "Antioch University Los Angeles", "Antioch University Midwest", 
"Antioch University Santa Barbara", "Antioch University Seattle", 
"Apex School of Theology", "Appalachian Bible College", "Appalachian State University", 
"Aquinas College", "Aquinas College", "Arapahoe Community College", 
"Arcadia University", "Arizona Christian University", "Arizona State University", 
"Arizona Western College", "Arkansas Baptist College", "Arkansas Northeastern College", 
"Arkansas State University", "Arkansas State University Mid-South", 
"Arkansas State University: Beebe", "Arkansas State University: Mountain Home", 
"Arkansas State University: Newport"), state = c("Montana", "Texas", 
"Georgia", "Minnesota", "California", "Colorado", "New York", 
"New York", "Michigan", "Virginia", "Florida", "Georgia", "South Carolina", 
"Colorado", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "North Carolina", 
"Alaska", "Alaska", "New York", "Georgia", "Georgia", "Connecticut", 
"Michigan", "Pennsylvania", "Mississippi", "West Virginia", "Minnesota", 
"New York", "California", "Maryland", "Pennsylvania", "Ohio", 
"Iowa", "Kansas", "South Carolina", "California", "Michigan", 
"Michigan", "Pennsylvania", "Wisconsin", "Texas", "Texas", "Texas", 
"New York", "Illinois", "New York", "California", "Tennessee", 
"Arizona", "Massachusetts", "California", "Virginia", "Virginia", 
"Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "Virginia", "West Virginia", 
"California", NA, NA, NA, "Massachusetts", "Alabama", "Indiana", 
"South Carolina", "Indiana", "Georgia", "Michigan", "Texas", 
"Texas", "Massachusetts", "Maryland", "Minnesota", "Minnesota", 
"California", "Ohio", "California", "Ohio", "California", "Washington", 
"North Carolina", "West Virginia", "North Carolina", "Michigan", 
"Tennessee", "Colorado", "Pennsylvania", "Arizona", "Arizona", 
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", "Arkansas", 
"Arkansas", "Arkansas"), state_abbr = c("MT", "TX", "GA", "MN", 
"CA", "CO", "NY", "NY", "MI", "VA", "FL", "GA", "SC", "CO", "AL", 
"AL", "AL", "NC", "AK", "AK", "NY", "GA", "GA", "CT", "MI", "PA", 
"MS", "WV", "MN", "NY", "CA", "MD", "PA", "OH", "IA", "KS", "SC", 
"CA", "MI", "MI", "PA", "WI", "TX", "TX", "TX", "NY", "IL", "NY", 
"CA", "TN", "AZ", "MA", "CA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", "VA", 
"WV", "CA", "AS", "DC", "PR", "MA", "AL", "IN", "SC", "IN", "GA", 
"MI", "TX", "TX", "MA", "MD", "MN", "MN", "CA", "OH", "CA", "OH", 
"CA", "WA", "NC", "WV", "NC", "MI", "TN", "CO", "PA", "AZ", "AZ", 
"AZ", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR", "AR"), type = c("Public", 
"Private", "Public", "For Profit", "For Profit", "Public", "Private", 
"Public", "Private", "For Profit", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "For Profit", "For Profit", 
"For Profit", "For Profit", "For Profit", "For Profit", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Public", 
"Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", "Public", "Public", 
"Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Private", "Private", "Public", "Private", 
"Private", "Public", "Public", "Private", "Public", "Public", 
"Public", "Public", "Public", "Public"), degree_length = c("2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", "4 Year", 
"2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "4 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", "2 Year", 
"2 Year"), room_and_board = c(NA, 10350, 8474, NA, 16648, 8782, 
16030, 11660, 11318, NA, 4200, 12330, NA, NA, 8379, NA, 5422, 
NA, 5700, 7300, 10920, 8878, NA, 13200, 12380, 12070, 9608, 8860, 
NA, 12516, NA, NA, 12140, 4000, 7282, 5070, 7230, NA, 10998, 
NA, NA, 8546, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 17955, 13255, 8640, 6250, 14300, 
17362, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 14880, NA, 14740, 
NA, 9600, 9830, 9890, 10636, 9078, 5500, 9130, 14630, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 7640, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7960, 8304, 9332, NA, NA, 13800, 
10674, 12648, 6700, 8826, NA, 8160, NA, 5280, NA, NA), in_state_tuition = c(2380, 
34850, 4128, 17661, 27810, 9440, 38660, 5375, 37087, 13680, 15150, 
41160, 5160, 2281, 9698, 4440, 11068, 2310, 9300, 20830, 35105, 
6726, 3246, 32060, 45775, 45306, 7144, 27910, 5416, 33484, 1418, 
4140, 47540, 6400, 19970, 3150, 13340, 18000, 40258, 4530, 34885, 
28302, 1998, 2670, 12840, 17160, 34100, 35160, 35160, 10950, 
958, 35680, 31826, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 
8150, 1416, 3700, 48459, 6946, 56426, 6900, 17330, 28000, 30450, 
17388, 29288, 2625, 8489, 37860, 4110, 5584, 5073, 1420, 35718, 
20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 6200, 14720, 7214, 32574, 23600, 
4811, 43580, 26796, 10822, 2520, 8760, 2450, 8608, 3274, 3600, 
3570, 3480), in_state_total = c(2380, 45200, 12602, 17661, 44458, 
18222, 54690, 17035, 48405, 13680, 19350, 53490, 5160, 2281, 
18077, 4440, 16490, 2310, 15000, 28130, 46025, 15604, 3246, 45260, 
58155, 57376, 16752, 36770, 5416, 46000, 1418, 4140, 59680, 10400, 
27252, 8220, 20570, 18000, 51256, 4530, 34885, 36848, 1998, 2670, 
12840, 17160, 34100, 53115, 48415, 19590, 7208, 49980, 49188, 
18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 8150, 1416, 3700, 63339, 
6946, 71166, 6900, 26930, 37830, 40340, 28024, 38366, 8125, 17619, 
52490, 4110, 5584, 5073, 1420, 43358, 20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 
6200, 22680, 15518, 41906, 23600, 4811, 57380, 37470, 23470, 
9220, 17586, 2450, 16768, 3274, 8880, 3570, 3480), out_of_state_tuition = c(2380, 
34850, 12550, 17661, 27810, 20456, 38660, 9935, 37087, 13680, 
15150, 41160, 8010, 13018, 17918, 8880, 19396, 8070, 9300, 20830, 
35105, 19802, 5916, 32060, 45775, 45306, 7144, 27910, 5416, 33484, 
7898, 9210, 47540, 6400, 19970, 3150, 13340, 18000, 40258, 6840, 
34885, 28302, 4818, 5880, 12840, 17160, 34100, 35160, 35160, 
10950, 958, 35680, 31826, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 
18735, 8150, 9546, 3700, 48459, 6946, 56426, 6900, 17330, 28000, 
30450, 17388, 29288, 5535, 20939, 37860, 12180, 5584, 5073, 9760, 
35718, 20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 6200, 14720, 22021, 32574, 
23600, 18671, 43580, 26796, 28336, 9510, 8760, 4250, 15298, 5014, 
5760, 5580, 5310), out_of_state_total = c(2380, 45200, 21024, 
17661, 44458, 29238, 54690, 21595, 48405, 13680, 19350, 53490, 
8010, 13018, 26297, 8880, 24818, 8070, 15000, 28130, 46025, 28680, 
5916, 45260, 58155, 57376, 16752, 36770, 5416, 46000, 7898, 9210, 
59680, 10400, 27252, 8220, 20570, 18000, 51256, 6840, 34885, 
36848, 4818, 5880, 12840, 17160, 34100, 53115, 48415, 19590, 
7208, 49980, 49188, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 18735, 
8150, 9546, 3700, 63339, 6946, 71166, 6900, 26930, 37830, 40340, 
28024, 38366, 11035, 30069, 52490, 12180, 5584, 5073, 9760, 43358, 
20670, 16210, 22575, 27435, 6200, 22680, 30325, 41906, 23600, 
18671, 57380, 37470, 40984, 16210, 17586, 4250, 23458, 5014, 
11040, 5580, 5310)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Ordering anything in `ggplot2` (whether facets or axis labels or colors) is almost always resolved with `factor`s, controlling the order of their `levels`. The [`forcats`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forcats/index.html) simplifies this a bit, though it is not required.

Comment: Please post plaintext output, not images.

Comment: @BillO'Brien, what do you mean? the only image currently in the question is the `ggplot2` rendering. And since the question is about graphic properties, I think having the plot is not inappropriate. (I agree that many questions over-use images instead of text/data, but I think this is not one of them.)

Comment: Oh, my workplace doesn't resolve links to image hosting sites, so all I see is a broken link.

Comment: Huh. Seeing as how that's Stack's imgur repository of images, that must crush you on just about every question on SO. It *does* lend to a suggestion to improve the "alt-text" of images. I've updated the alt-text here (as a *suggestion* to Eric), does that make it less of an issue to you? (I'm asking also in general, not just this question, since I try to use alt-text myself to facilitate both visually-impaired as well as network-policy-impaired.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and suggestions @r2evans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Change to a factor, changing your `label` creation to be

```r
  mutate(
    label = paste(pct_change * 100,"%"),
    label = factor(label, levels = unique(label[order(-pct_change)])),
  ) %>%
```

---

Full code:

```r
tuition_cost_clean %>% 
  filter(!is.na(room_and_board),
         degree_length == "4 Year",
         state_abbr %in% top_colleges_pct_change) %>% 
  arrange(state, desc(in_state_total)) %>%
  group_by(state_abbr) %>% 
  slice(which.max(in_state_total), which.min(in_state_total)) %>% 
  mutate(pct_change = round(-diff(in_state_total) / max(in_state_total),3),) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  top_n(n = 24, wt = pct_change) %>% 
  select(name, state_abbr, in_state_total, pct_change) %>% 
  ## start modified code
  mutate(
    label = paste(pct_change * 100,"%"), # (unchanged)
    label = factor(label, levels = unique(label[order(-pct_change)])),
  ) %>% 
  ## end modified code
  ggplot(aes(x = state_abbr, y = in_state_total, fill = name))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5)+
  facet_wrap(~label, scales = "free")+
  labs(title = "States with Largest Difference Between Highest and Lowest Costing 4-Year Colleges\n2018-2019",
       x = "State",
       y = "In-State Total Cost")+
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.title = element_text(size = 12))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar)
```

[image: ggplot with corrected facet-ordering]

Comment: I usually don't like asking additional questions, but why are some facets showing the lower value bar on the left while other facets are showing it on the right? Is there a way to make it uniform across the facets with the larger bar on the left and the smaller bar on the right?

Comment: (Sorry, I just locked up my R so I cannot test easily ...) I'm guessing it'd also be a `factor` thing. There's no other way that I know of to suggest to `ggplot2` the order of facets or objects or such: it finds some meaningful order (often alphabetic) and sticks with it. `factor`s are the easy way for it to stop inferring and do what you insist.